# Shorter URL alias, like ips.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request

The domain http://interpersonal.stackexchange.com is painfully long to type. Some sites with long names use abbreviations in the URL, like http://dsp.stackexchange.com or http://sqa.stackexchange.com

I don't propose changing the main URL, though. Just add http://ips.stackexchange.com as an alias. There are precedents, like http://elu.stackexchange.com  being an alias for http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: At the same time, it would be nice if `[ips.se]` could be expanded automatically like it is for `[inter​personal.se]`, creating the link to [interpersonal.se]